# Django url patterns - how to get absolute url to the page?

Tags: django, url, url-pattern

i'm trying to get full path of the requested url in Django. I use a such url pattern:
    ('^', myawesomeview),
It works good for domain.com/hello, domain.com/hello/sdfsdfsd and even for domain.com/hello.php/sd""^some!bullshit.index.aspx (although, "^" is replaced with "%5E")

But when I try to use # in request (ex. http://127.0.0.1:8000/solid#url) it returns only "/sold". Is there any way to get the full path without ANY changes or replacements?

BTW, I'getting url with return HttpResponse(request.path)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part of URI separated by '#' sign is called a fragment identifier. Its sense is to be processed on client side only, and not to be passed to server. So if you really need this, you have to process it with JS, for example, and pass it as a usual parameter. Otherwise, this information will never be sent to Django.